# passing 2 array dialog but wen save added me another position with a randomId

Tags: angular, typescript

I am passing into dialog just editPosition, but I want to pass both of them editPosition and budget. How can I achieve that? I want to upsert both of them and when I upsert the editPosition and budget should upserted not take another id.

Here is the code.

This is the template that is a function.

```
<li class="fa fa-pencil clickable fa-fw" 
    (click)="openEditPositionDialog(position)"></li>
```

This is the TS that opens the dialog:

```
openEditPositionDialog(position, budget) {
    const editPosition = Object.assign({}, position, budget);
    this.dialog.open(PositionEditDialogComponent,
        {data: editPosition, disableClose: true}
    );
}
```

And here what is in Typescript when I want to save:

```
constructor(
    public store: Store<ApplicationState>,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PositionEditDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public editPosition
) {}

ngOnInit() {}

save() {
    this.working = true;
    this.editPosition.PositionCostType = this.editPosition.newCostType;
    this.editPosition.PositionCurrency = this.editPosition.newCurrency;
    this.editPosition.PositionState = this.editPosition.newState;
    this.store.dispatch(new 
    UpsertPositionInternalAction(this.editPosition));
}
```

This is the position when is saved

```
 save() {
  this.working = true;
  const newPosition: Position = emptyPosition();
  const newBudget: Budget = emptyBudget();
  newPosition.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(3, 2);
  newBudget.id = Math.random().toString(20).substr(3, 2);
  newPosition.name = this.newPositionName;
  newPosition.state = this.newState;
  newBudget.planned = this.planned;
  newPosition.budgetIds.push(newBudget.id); // = 
  newPosition.currency = this.newCurrency;
  newPosition.costType = this.newCostType;
  this.subproject.positionIds.push(newPosition.id);
  this.store.dispatch(new UpsertPositionInternalAction(newPosition));
  this.store.dispatch(new UpsertBudgetInternalAction(newBudget));
  this.store.dispatch(new 
UpsertSubProjectInternalAction(this.subproject));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can just wrap those arrays with an object : `{data : {editPosition, budget}, disableClose: true}`?

Comment: @wprzechodzen It is not working, because now when the dialog is open nothing is shown and when i upsert it is adding me another position not editing this one.

Comment: Well, replace `openEditPositionDialog(position)` by `openEditPositionDialog(position, someBudget)`. We have no idea what you want to pass as budget, and where it comes from, though.

Comment: @JBNizet the budget comes from another interface,  here is the code when i save a position.
 I updated the question you can see the position when is saved.

Comment: @JBNizet When i save a position at planned budget is saved planned of interface Budget all others are saved in the position.
When I edit something in the dit dialog everything changes just the planned budget doesn't change I tried to upsert store but takes another id.

Comment: I have no idea of what you're saying. Your question is "I am passing into dialog just editPosition, but I want to pass both of them editPosition and budget.". This has nothing to do with saving, a store, or anything else. It just has to do with passing two arguments to your method, since it expects two, instead of passing only the first one.

Comment: I tried your answer but didn't work, could you write how to pass two arguments and in the dialog how to inject both of them.

Comment: I already said that. But I still have no idea of where the budget that you must pass to your openEditPositionDialog() method comes from. Which budget do you want to pass? Why do you pass a single argument to a method expecting two? What's preventing you from passing the second one?

Comment: Budget comes from another interface because id of budget is pushed into position.budgetIds and when i upsert the  position should be upserted this budget that the id is into position.budgetIds because position.plannedBudget it referes to interface of budget.planned.
I want when i change budget in the dialog when is saved should show in the line of position.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "from another interface". Again. You chose to add a method `openEditPositionDialog(position, budget)` in your component. It expects a position, and a budget. But then you chose to call this method the following way: `(click)="openEditPositionDialog(position)"`. As you see (hopefully), you're passing a single argument, but the method expects two. Why do you do that? Why don't you pass the expected second argument? What is the problem in passing the expected second argument?

Comment: I did it but now when I edit a position when i click save add another position, I want to change the current position, I didn't ask for this but I am little new to angular. How can I achieve that.